# Invalid JSON require Swift iOS

Tags: php, ios, json, swift, wordpress

I am developing a simple `iOS` `Swift` app. I want to make a log-in screen for my app that will connect to already existing user database in `Wordpress`. I found some `PHP` scripts and `Swift` code.

I am trying to post username and login, check it and return the result(isUser = true/false or 1/0)

Here is a PHP script

```
<?php
// Read request parameters
$username= $_REQUEST["username"];
$password = $_REQUEST["password"];
// Store values in an array
$returnValue = array("username"=>$username, "password"=>$password);
// Send back request in JSON format
echo json_encode($returnValue);
?>
```

and a Swift function

```
func getPHPJson() {

    let urlPath: String = "LINK_TO_PHP_FILE?username=\(user)&password=\(pass)"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let request1: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    request1.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    do 
    {
        if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary 
        {
            print(jsonResult)
            //print(jsonResult["isUser"] as! Bool)
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("raw response: \(responseString!)")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError 
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print("error")
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("raw response: \(responseString)")
    }
    })
}
```

it gives me a desired result.

**OUTPUT**

```
{
    password = iosappusettest1;
    username = iosappusettest;
}
raw response: {"username":"iosappusettest","password":"iosappusettest1"}
```

But when I add function to check if user is registered - I always get an **invalid JSON**

here is PHP function

```
function authentication ($user, $pass){
  global $wp, $wp_rewrite, $wp_the_query, $wp_query;

  if(empty($user) || empty($pass)){
    return 0;
  } else {
    require_once('../wp-blog-header.php');
    $status = 0;
    $auth = wp_authenticate($user, $pass );
    if( is_wp_error($auth) ) {      
      $status = 0;
    } else {
      $status = 1;
    }
    return $status;
  } 
}
```

I believe the problem is `require_once` function. In raw response I get a lot of `html` tags and other data that make my `JSON` invalid.

- Is there any way to clear the page and output in the `JSON` only? `echo "<script> document.documentElement.innerHTML = ''; </script>";` in PHP did't help me. maybe jQuery will help?
- Maybe I can check if user is registered in another way?
- Maybe I can store my result in a separate place or temp file?
- Maybe I should wrap my data not in JSON but something else?

So I need to pass username and password to PHP, check it with authentication function(that uses `require_once`) and send back the $status to `iOS` `Swift` app ass variable.

**Question is answered.**
The problem was in WP plugin, that redirected all unlogined users from all the links in that domain, so when i called `require_once('../wp-blog-header.php');` i was always redirected to main page and that was the reason for wrong JSON file with all the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your response in pure JSON, and leave out any html tags as they are not needed by your ios end.

Comment: with a big pleasure but i can't. The problem is that when i add authentication function(that uses require_once) - i always get invalid JSON and html tags.

Comment: I don't know php, but I think your invalid JSON is just a `0`? Your first php snippet returns json correctly. You could try to return something similar to that in your authentication method.

Comment: The problem is your php code does not return correct JSON.

Comment: I checked one more time. Still get error. *The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.*after require_once in php file I get a lot of different tags as <style>some styles</style> and <script>some scripts</script> and so on..

Comment: Find some useful library in php that deals with json.